# toolbar inflate from fragment not working at first drawer layout creation of the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

### Introduction

I have an activity (let's call **BaseActivity**) that initializes the drawer layout in **onPostCreate**

```
public void initDrawerLayout(){
    setSupportActionBar(getYellowToolbar());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_menu));

    // Toggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 
    getYellowToolbar(), R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new UiHelper());
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    findViewById(R.id.menu_back).setOnClickListener(new 
    View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listmenu);
    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);

    mExpandableMenuAdapter = getMenuAdapter();
    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableMenuAdapter);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Then I have a specific fragment working under an Activity which extends BaseActity.
This fragment adds to the top toolbar (yellowtoolbar) at **onResume** time an additional button inside R.menu.scanner_menu.

```
Toolbar toolbar = getYellowToolbar();
if (toolbar == null)
    return;

toolbar.getMenu().clear();
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.scanner_menu);
/**
 * Add click listener on scan
 */
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        .
        .
        return false;
    }
});
```

### Situation

```
           BaseActivity onPostCreate init drawer layout

              ChildrenActivity extends BaseActivity
            Fragment inflates new button onResume
```

### Problem

When I reach this fragment from another fragment belonging to the same activity the inflate of the additional button is **successful** and I can click it with no problem.
While if I starts the application (so the onPostCreate of the BaseActivity is called) having the fragment to be shown at first so both the initDrawerLayout from BaseActivity and the inflate of the fragment are called **almost at the same time** the inflate of the additional button is **unsuccessful** and I cannot see it.

### Additional info

I have tried to add a generic button in the fragment and clicking on it inflates one more time the menu button in the top toolbar and it correctly works. I think the problem seems to be the toolbar rendering by the drawer layout initialization that is still not completed the moment the fragment inflates the new button, so the toolbar just skip the new button and goes on with the BaseActivity.

Comment: In your description, you first say "fragment adds to the top toolbar (yellowtoolbar) at __onResume__", but then "Fragment inflates new button onViewCreated". Where are you trying to inflate that menu, exactly? `onViewCreated()` is too soon, but I would think that `onResume()` should work.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected it. It doesn't work in both ways.

Comment: OK. Any reason you're not initializing the drawer stuff from `onCreate()` instead (except for `mDrawerToggle.syncState()`)? Also, what's happening exactly when it fails? That is, does `getYellowToolbar()` return null in that `Fragment` block? Or does it reach the `inflateMenu()` call?